# VSCode Not Recognizing Python Imports from 'src' Folder in Nested Project Structure

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import, type-hinting, pylint

I'm experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code (both standard and Insiders versions on Mac Sonoma 14.0) where it fails to recognize import statements in a specific nested project structure. The structure of my project is as follows:

```
- project/
  - sub_project_1/
    - src/
      - utils.py
    - main.py
  - ...
```

In `main.py`, I have the following import statement: `from src import utils`. Strangely, VSCode does not recognize this import. However, if I rename the `src` folder to something else, like `source` or `src2`, then the imports are recognized without any issues.

Additionally, this problem only occurs when I have the `project` folder open in VSCode. If I open just the `sub_project_1` folder directly in VSCode, the imports work as expected.

This is a new issue for me; in previous projects with a similar structure and using the `src` folder, I haven't encountered this problem. I'm wondering if this could be related to a recent update in VSCode, or if there's something specific about my current setup that's causing this issue.

Attempts to Resolve: I've tried renaming the folder, which seems to fix the issue, suggesting it's related to the specific naming of the 'src' folder.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide insight into what might be causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Does the error persist when an empty `__init__.py` file exists in the `src` directory?

Comment: Yes it still persists. To be clear it's not an error in a sense that the code executes fine. VSCode editor is just not seeing the import. I wonder if others can replicate this with the most recent version of vscode and its standard python extensions.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to that link. It's not about importing from sibling project. It's about vscode not recognizing keyword "src". Python execution works fine.